# Removing an index from a list if it contains a specific value

Tags: python, list

Im looking to remove several indices from a list, and want to filter them by content. For example:

```
L= [(1, 2, 3), (etc, etc, etc), (......)]
if L[i] == 1:
    L[i] == nan
>>>L
[(nan), (etc, etc.......]
```

I know this code isn't correct, but it's just an example to help iterate what I want to do, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a list comprehension:

```
L = [float('nan') if el[0] == 1 else el for el in L]
```

The `if .. else ..` part is called a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

This *replaces* the list with a new list. If you have multiple references to the same list, you can replace the *elements* of the list instead with a slice assignment:

```
L[:] = [float('nan') if el[0] == 1 else el for el in L]
```

Now all elements in `L` will be replaced with all the elements produced by the list comprehension. The difference between the two expressions is subtle but crucial; the first rebinds `L` to point to a new list, the second retains that list but only replaces the elements contained in the list itself.

Answer (score 2):

L[:] will modify the same list.

This checks if the item contains 1 at 0th index, if `True` use `nan` else use the item as it is.

```
nan = float('nan')
L[:] = [nan if item[0] == 1 else item for item in L]
```

Perhaps you're trying to do something like this this:

This checks if the item contains 1 at any position not just 0th, if True use nan else use the item as it is.

```
L[:] = [nan if 1 in item else item for item in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the element you're checking...

```
index_to_check = 3
if my_list[index_to_check] == bad_value:
    del my_list[index_to_check]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to remove it I would suggest a filter:

```
filter(1, L)
```

If you want to do something else with it a list comprehension would be the best approach, but I wasn't sure whether I should follow your title or your example.

So long as you are filtering on a specific value and not the evaluation of a lambda function it should be significantly more performant than a list comprehension.

If you're looking for something a little more complicated a list comprehension would be the best approach since lambda functions are going out of favour for applications like these.

```
replacement = float('nan')
condition = 1
L = [replacement if item == condition else item for item in L]
L = [replacement if item[index] == condition else item for item in L]
```

You could fuse multiple solutions and use a lambda function for your condition by changing one of the above examples to something like this:

```
replacement = float('nan')
condition = lambda x: x[0]==1
L = [replacement if condition(item) else item for item in L]
```

If you really like lambda functions you could even wrap the whole thing in a lambda function

```
custom_filter = lambda x: [float('nan') if item[0]==1 else item for item in x]
L = custom_filter(L)
```

Those solutions are in rough order by performance, but it really depends on your particular application and what exactly your problem is. If you want to use this on a number of different lists, even though the `custom_filter` object has the additional overhead of making a function call, readability would increase, and if you're using it many times in succession the performance difference would go away since the lambda function would get cached.

The filter will be screaming fast, but really isn't as flexible as the others, the second method is very close to your original meaning, but the third example is probably the most modular and is honestly the solution I would probably use just since it leads to readable and general code.